# Python compression of many objects with a single compression table

Tags: python, compression, zlib

Consider many (10s or 100s of millions) of fairly short (around 100 ascii character) strings that contain many repeated sub-strings. I'd like to use the strings in a Python program, but compress them to save space.
Most compression algorithms, like Lempel–Ziv (LZ), use a lookup table to encode compressed data.
Is there a way to use an existing compression library (like [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), [zlib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html)) to do this? In pseudo code, to compress the data one would make the calls

```
table = zlib.makeTable( data )
foreach string:
    compressedString = zlib.compressString( table, string )
```

and then store the compressed strings.

Comment: Im not sure your assumptions are correct on how most compression algorithms work ... certainly some do ... however its not usually arbitrary  and it happens behind the scenes (not explicitly like in your example)

Comment: Interesting question. From the docs of *zlib* (the C library, not the Python module), http://www.zlib.net/manual.html, I see there is a function `deflateSetDictionary()` which does about the same as your `makeTable` example. For decompression you'd use `inflateSetDictionary()`. You'd use `deflate()` and `inflate()` to do the actual compression and decompression after determining the compression tables. Now, these are functions in a C library, so some work is involved calling them from Python, but that's already a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like you said, but there is a way to do what I think you're asking for.  [zlib](http://zlib.net/) has a function `deflateSetDictionary()` that you can use to prime the compressor with 32K of data that is, hopefully, representative of the short strings you are trying to compress.  You would construct it out of sample strings and/or portions of sample strings.